# SetSelectedDataAsync Html Data Stripped Out When Using Outlook Desktop

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-api

I am trying to add hidden data to an Outlook email from an outlook web add-in so that I can use it later for linking the email back to other data.

I am using the setSelectedDataAsync method for this like so:

```
var content = 
              "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hidEmailTracking\" value='{\"syntheticConversationId\":\"" 
              + syntheticConversationId + "\"" +
              ",\"staffId\":" + staffId +
              ",\"countryCode\":\"" +  countryCode + "\"}'/>";

              item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                content,
                {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html}, function (result) {
```

However, when I send the email, Outlook Web keeps the hidden field that I have added but Outlook Desktop seems to strip it out. The email is set to HTML format.

Is there a way to mark the hidden html so that it doesn't get removed? Or alternatively is there another way of transporting hidden data in an outlook email that is compatible with both Outlook web and desktop?

thanks

Comment: The new Internet Headers api may help you in transferring properties across sent items: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: That looks like it could be just what I am looking for. Does it work in  both desktop and web based outlook? The other part of this is that I later intercept the email using Azure logic apps so thg is working will depend on the outlook connector in Logic apps passing me back the x-header. Definitely hopeful though and would potentially solve another problem for me ... handling plain text emails as well as html based ones. I'll try it out when I'm back at work tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried this out and as suspected, unfortunately even though I can see the custom headers have been added to the email but when I retrieve the email via the Logic App Outlook Connector, the headers are gone. A possible solution would be if I could get the email using the Graph API and get the headers that way but I'm not seeing anything suggesting that you can do that.

Comment: I've promoted our previous comment to an answer. Retrieving the internet headers via Graph API or some other mechanism is another discussion/post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an internet headers API that can be used to achieve your scenario. Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview